# NodeJS with NGINx and Moodle with Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, moodle

I have a website that was built with wordpress (the information bit) and moodle (for students exams and whatnot), now I've re-built it using NodeJS and I'm having some trouble deploying it since there is already a website up. I want to use NGINx as a reverse proxy to serve my node app but keep the Moodle part so, for example:

User goes to www.myweb.com and sees the node (MEAN stack) app, then he/she can go to www.myweb.com/classroom which is Moodle. Since Moodle is beign serve by Apache I'm not quite sure how to have both node and Moodle up.

Comment: You can do reverse proxy using node...

Comment: And why serving with Apache? Moodle should run fine  with nginx

Comment: @Bearzi because it is already that way, I did not make that I'm just re-doing the website and instead of LAMP stack I did it in MEAN stack and I'm jsut having trouble in how to deploy it and not lose what's already up.

Comment: @SandeshK this doesn't answer anything. Yes I can do it with node, but I can do it with nginx too, which is what I intent and what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a proxy script in nginx configuration file.

(Change port number of your apache server to something other than 80, as this port will be used by nginx.)

Install nginx.

Edit your configuration file to add a server:

(Remove or edit existing server block that listens to port 80.)

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:<port_number>;
        }
        location /classroom/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:<port_number>;
        }
    }
}
```

Restart nginx.

Refer this for more information: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: this means that the every request to location / will be served by node and every request to location /classroom/ will be served by apache?